# How to manage active operations on AFNetworking (AFDownloadRequestOperation)

Tags: ios, http, afnetworking, objective-c-blocks, nsoperation

I'm starting with iOS, and I'm trying to code a simple file downloader, with a webview.

I need to download multiple files, but not called at the same time (like examples I've seen); It should be just like a desktop browser: it should be able to add a new operation while browsing, at any time, not all the downloads in a row...

After reading and reading, I discovered afnetworking, and I've been trying to implement it with no good results... because I don't know how to manage multiple operations!

My question is, once I've added many operations, how can I call them individually? For example, to stop or cancel just one of them.

This is the code:

```
...
    AFHTTPClient *httpClient;
...


- (void)DownloadFileFromUrl:(NSString *)fileURL{

        NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:fileURL];
        NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];

     //I've tried to init httpClient here each time, or at didLoad with a nil baseurl

     httpClient =[[AFHTTPClient alloc]initWithBaseURL: [NSURL URLWithString:@"fileURL"]];
    [httpClient.operationQueue setMaxConcurrentOperationCount:10];

    AFDownloadRequestOperation *operation = [[AFDownloadRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request
                                                                                     targetPath:targetPath
                                                                                   shouldResume:YES];


        [operation setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) {

            //COOL!

        } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
            //failure case


            //remove the file if saved a part of it!
            NSFileManager *fileManager = [NSFileManager defaultManager];
            [fileManager removeItemAtPath:targetPath error:&error];

            if (error) {

                //ERROR

            }

            if ([operation isCancelled]) {



            }
        }];

    [operation setProgressiveDownloadProgressBlock:^(AFDownloadRequestOperation *operation1, NSInteger bytesRead, long long totalBytesRead, long long totalBytesExpected, long long totalBytesReadForFile, long long totalBytesExpectedToReadForFile)
     {



            if (totalBytesExpectedToReadForFile > 0) {
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{


                //NSLog(@"Operation%i: bytesRead: %d", 1, bytesRead);
                //NSLog(@"Operation%i: totalBytesRead: %lld", 1, totalBytesRead);
                //NSLog(@"Operation%i: totalBytesExpected: %lld", 1, totalBytesExpected);
                //NSLog(@"Operation%i: totalBytesReadForFile: %lld", 1, totalBytesReadForFile);
                //NSLog(@"Operation%i: totalBytesExpectedToReadForFile: %lld", 1, totalBytesExpectedToReadForFile);



            });
        }

     }];


       [httpClient.operationQueue addOperation:operation];
        //OR ?[httpClient enqueueHTTPRequestOperation:operation];


}
```

When I download only one file, everything seems ok, because calling httpClient.operationQueue.operations[0]... I get the data of it, and I can't do, from anywhere, a [[httpClient.operationQueue.operations[0]] pause];

However, if I try to download a second file from another site (I have a webview to navigate), and add it to httpClient.operationQueue, it doesn't seem to add it to the same queue; I mean, if I call with a timer this:

```
NSLog(@"Operations %d", httpClient.operationQueue.operations.count);
```

I don get "Operations 2", but:

```
Operations 1
Operations 1
```

That's annoying, because sometimes when I try to get the operations.count in order to find my desired operation and do something with it, i don't find it! It's in a "parallel" Queue or something!

It's there a way to get and handle all the active operations? Or a way to store each operation on some kind of array each time I add one? (but being able to "use them", not for read-only purposes.. like calling pause, cancel, etc)

It's obvious that I'm missing something important, and that I'm a beginner in programming, but any help would be really appreciated! (and please, if you can be explicit, much better.. I'm a beginner)

Thank you very much, really.

**EDIT:**
After doing a little research, and trying some things, I've solved it adding that httpclient to a singleton,and setting it only when App initializes, with a random baseurl. Then I add each operation to that Singleton-httpClient, despite its url. It seems to work, because now it stores all the conections and I can access them with now problems looping it, but I know that it's not the good way; it HAS to be easier on cleaner, and I know I'm missing the way of managing the active connections in some kind of array, instead of using a "tricky" httpclient with a fake baseurl for all operations (with different urls)
So... I'm still accepting advices and good practices :). Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay some tips before hand.
I strongly recommend you to read both NSOperationQueue and NSOperation API doc:

NSOperationQueue:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004592

NSOperation:
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperation_class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40004591

I discourage you to try to iterate over NSOperationQueue's operations array. Why? Because it's high probably you'll end with a race condition problem.

However. I suggest you the following approach:

1) Create a NSDictionary in your singleton class where:
key: will represent the file name
value:  the AFDownloadRequestOperation request associate with that request.

2) When you need to download a new file:
Verify if exists in your dictionary, if doesn't create a new operation and add it to the dictionary.

2.1) If it does exists you might want:
2.1.1) Since AFDownloadRequestOperation extends from NSOperation you can cancel it. To do this before you have to check this conditions: isExecuting, isFinished. If any of those conditions are false you can cancel the operation and remove it from your dictionary.